# How to read html data using R

Tags: r

I am trying to read the table data from [this url](http://www.forbes.com/powerful-brands/list/#tab:rank)

This is what I have come up with

```
d1 <- htmlParse("http://www.forbes.com/powerful-brands/list/#tab:rank")
d2 <- xpathApply(d1,"//tbody")
```

This gives me just the table headers but not the actual values in it.
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I consider this as a tiny project instead of a question.

Comment: Part of a project! yes

Comment: when i try d1 <- readhtmlTable("http://www.forbes.com/powerful-brands/list/#tab:rank"), it is the same issue. It gives me table headers

Comment: You should probably read point 1.3 of http://www.forbes.com/terms and others shld consider not violating the Forbes ToS to provide solutions.

Answer (score 0):

```
dat1 <- htmlparse("url")
dat2 <- getNodeSet(dat1,"//table")
```

This works fine. Do suggest if it can be done in a better way

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Instead, **[accept the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)** that you found most helpful.  - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/12356134)

Comment: @Filburt there are no other answers and this doesn't say "thank you" anywhere.

Comment: If you are sure this is the answer, it's fine. If you expect better answers, you should edit this into your question and not post as an answer. The wording suggests that this is meant as a comment rather than an answer.